# The line before a $timeout is not working (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have

```
vm.showSuccess = true;
$timeout(function() { close(); }, 2000);
vm.showSuccess = false;
```

The timeout function works fine, but the first line does not get fired.

I'm basically using this as a success message after a submit on a form

Comment: it is fired at the time of controller initialization

Comment: I guess you wanted it to be fire after `close()` call like `$timeout(function() { close(); vm.showSuccess = false; }, 2000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to change this to something like

```
vm.showSuccess = true;

$timeout(function () {
  close();
  vm.showSuccess = false;
}, 2000);
```

What's happening in your code is that the controller gets initialised and at that time `vm.showSuccess` is set to true, and on line 3 it gets set to false immediately, which is giving you the idea of it not getting executed.

Note how in my code example your last line is actually inside the `$timeout` so that is executes 2 seconds later.